# Generating function of a sequence involving reciprocals of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions

Question: Is there a closed-form expression for the following sum

$$ 
F(z,k,r)=\sum_{n=0}^{r} \frac{z^n}{{n+k} \choose {k}}\label{sum}\tag{1}
$$

where $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and $r$, $k$ are non-negative integers.

Remark: Obviously, the above expression is a polynomial of degree $r$. However, I am interested in "alternative" expressions for it as later on I will need to compute residues of the product of above functions (see below).

Motivation: I am trying to compute a much nastier expression involving sum over  multisets and ratios of multinomial coefficients:

$$
\sum_{(n_1,\ldots,n_d)\vdash N-k}\dfrac{{{k} \choose {k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_d}} {{N-k} \choose {n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_d}} }{ {{N} \choose {n_1+k_1,n_2+k_2,\ldots,n_d+k_d}}}\label{ssum}\tag{2}
$$

where $N,k$ are fixed non-negative integers and $(k_1,\ldots,k_d)$ is fixed and satisfies $(k_1,\ldots,k_d)\vdash k$.

I got expression $\eqref{sum}$ by trying to compute $\eqref{ssum}$ explicitly via the integral representation of [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Comment: Writing $\frac{F(z,k,r)}{k!} = \sum_{n=0}^r \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+k+1)} z^n = \sum_{n=0}^r\frac{z^n}{(n)_k}$ looks close to certain hypergeometricish functions I have seen but I am unsure if I know the name of them.

Comment: In case it is of any help, the generating function $G(x)=\sum_r F(z,k,r)x^r$ appears to satisfy $x(x-1)(xz-1)G'(x) + \big(x(2x-1)z -(k+1)x+k\big)G(x) - k = 0$.

Comment: (The generating function according to $k$ does not appear to be as nice.)

Comment: Mathematica writes it out as a difference of two ${}_2F_1$ hypergeometrics, but that seems to be perhaps not the "closed-form" you are after!

Comment: @Suvrit Note that the first of the hypergeometrics does not involve $r$

Comment: @Suvrit I should have mention this. Indeed I tried Mathematica and I got two hypergeometric functions. I was hoping for something nicer (As I mentioned I will need to compute residues of the multiple products product of these expressions...).

Comment: You can get the right polynomials from Mathematica using Limit[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, -r}, {k+1, -r + e}, z], e -> 0]  with r a positive integer. The negative "-r" in the "top" parameters will cause the hypergeometric sum to terminate. The "-r" in the bottom parameters eventually will cancel additional factors. The "+ e" prevents Mathematica from initially canceling the "-r"s. If you want to do any calculations, you have to keep the "e" until the end and then send it to zero. Of course, this is not mathematically rigorous, but at least a direction to go for numerical calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's solve Martin Rubey's differential equation, which I write as
$$g(x)G'(x) = f_1(x)G(x) + f_0(x),$$
where $g(x) = x(x-1)(xz-1)$, $f_1(x) = -x(2x-1)z+(k+1)x-k$, and $f_0(x)=k$.

Then by the [general formula](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0103.pdf), we compute
$$F(x) = \int \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)}\,dx = (k - 1) \ln(x z - 1) - k\ln(x) - \ln(x - 1),$$
and thus 
$$e^{F(x)} = \frac{(xz-1)^{k-1}}{x^k(x-1)}.$$
Then since $G(0)=1$, we get
$$G(x) = \frac{k(1-xz)^{k-1}}{x^k(1-x)} \int \frac{x^{k-1}}{(1-xz)^k}\,dx$$
$$= \frac{(1-xz)^{k-1}}{1-x} \sum_{t\geq 0} \frac{k}{k+t} \binom{-k}{t} (-z)^t x^t$$
$$ = \frac{(1-xz)^{k-1}}{1-x}\ {}_2F_1(k,k+2;k+1;-xz).$$

---

Extracting the coefficient of $x^r$:
$$[x^r]\ G(x) = \sum_{n\leq r}(-z)^n\sum_{t\geq 0} \frac{k}{k+t} \binom{-k}{t} \binom{k-1}{n-t},$$
we arrive at a remarkable identity
$$\sum_{t\geq 0} \frac{k}{k+t} \binom{-k}{t} \binom{k-1}{n-t} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom{n+k}k},$$
which holds for all $n\geq 0$ and $k\geq 1$.

Comment: The identity is a special case of Saalschütz's theorem. It can be generalized to 
$$\sum_{t\geq 0} \frac{a}{a+t} \binom{-k}{t} \binom{k-1}{n-t} = (-1)^n\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{n+a}k}.$$

Comment: @IraGessel: Thanks for the pointer! I suspected it'd be well-known.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I like it a lot. In the end we managed to proceed without using the generating function explicitly,  see  page 22 of https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.041044 (I realize that it is not straightforward to translate these computations to the original question...). Anyway, let me remark that in a variety of cases group-theoretic methods can yield complicated combinatoric identities.